# Efficient way to handle error cases in REST Apis

Tags: node.js, rest, hapi.js

I am writing a REST API in node.js. I expect at max 5 parameters to arrive in my GET Request. If there are unidentified parameters I wish to send 400 Bad Request.
Currently I am handling it in the following way:

```
server.route({
      method: "GET",
      path  : "/test",
      handler : function (request, reply) {

          if (request.query.a || request.query.b || request.query.c || request.query.d || request.query.e)
          {

             // do some processing
          }
          else {
             reply("No valid parameters").code(400);
           }
      }
});
```

Right now this does not handle the case if there are some valid and some invalid cases. I can solve that by using more if conditions. But I was just wondering if there is a standard or more efficient method which is used by developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hapi has built-in validation support. You can use [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) to validate the query:

```
var Joi = require('joi');

...

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/test',
    config: {
        validate: {
            query: {
                a: Joi.string(),
                b: Joi.string(),
                c: Joi.string(),
                d: Joi.string(),
                e: Joi.string()
            }
        }
    },
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        return reply('ok');
    }
});
```

If you send a request to `/test?g=foo`, then you get the following response:

```
{ statusCode: 400,
  error: 'Bad Request',
  message: '"g" is not allowed',
  validation: { source: 'query', keys: [ 'g' ] } }
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks great. I cannot test it right now, but does this allow for cases like only parameters a&b passed. If no parameters are passed will it return a 400? I am sorry as I am not in a position to test it out myself at the moment :(

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do any kind of validation with Joi. The code above will not return 400 if no parameters are passed, but it is possible to configure Joi to return 400 in that case. Your question is a bit too broad. I suggest to look at the documentation of Joi and try to create the validation schema. If you run into an issue, then open an other question and list which cases are valid and which cases are not.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually do this, but you are better off using a REST framework like mongoose or loopback (strongloop) to do the validation and error handling and other boilerplate code like model binding.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider the use of a framework, like [Express](http://expressjs.com), to use a [middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html) which is simply code you can reuse in different routes.

A simple pseudo/example looks like this

```
var app = express();

// a middleware with no mount path; gets executed for every request to the app
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.query.a && req.query.b) {
    return next()
  }
  else {
    return res.status(400).send('Not OK');
  }
});

// a route and its handler function (middleware system) which handles GET requests to /user/:id
app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  return res.send('OK');
});

// a different route, same middleware
app.get('/customer/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  return res.send('OK');
});
```